# Display a message if a form displays no results after filtering

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Below is what my VBA currently looks like. searchCrit is the Combo Box with various search criteria like First Name, Last Name, etc. and searchTxt is the value entered:

```
If searchCrit = "First Name" Then
    Me.Search_Results.Form.Filter = "[FirstName] LIKE '%" & searchTxt & "%'
    Me.Search_Results.Form.FilterOn = True

    If Me.Search_Results.Form.RecordCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox ("No Results Found")
    End If
Else If .......
```

I am getting an error on the line:

```
 If Me.Search_Results.Form.RecordCount < 1 Then
```

Is RecordCount not a viable method here? Is there some other way to detect if the form had returned no results?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
If Me!Search_Results.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No Results Found")
End If
```

Comment: "Application-defined or object-defined error." is what I got with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Would it be simpler to store the recordset in a query, run that and check if recordcount > 0 instead of trying to reference the form